# Is it possible in javascript to read local files in IE?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

FileReader allows to read local file in Chrome.

```
function readMultipleFiles(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files;

    if (files) {
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
            var r = new FileReader();
            r.onload = (function (f) {
                return function (e) {
                    var contents = e.target.result;
                    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = contents;
                };
            })(f);
            r.readAsText(f);
        }
    } else {
        alert("Failed to load files");
    }
}
document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readMultipleFiles, false);​
```

[Run example on jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/bHfEk/61/)

But this example does not work in Internet Explorer 9.
Does IE9 support File API?
If yes - what should I do to have ability to read local files in IE9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does IE9 support File API?

[No, it doesn't](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi).

> If yes - what should I do to have ability to read local files in IE9?

Did you mean *if no*? If so then you could use an ActiveX or just inform the user that this feature of your website is not supported on his browser and allow him the possibility to upload the file to the server.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I do now want to use ActiveX. I need this feature for local application that will be used by our team only. So I can just say that my application is compatible with Chrome and Mozilla.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ActiveX' FileSystemObject.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ty6h50%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var a = fso.CreateTextFile("c:\\testfile.txt", true);
a.WriteLine("This is a test.");
a.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you make an hypertext application (.hta), you will be able to create the ActiveX object `FileSystemObject`, which will let you access the local file system.

Answer (score 1):

Generally no.  Reading local files is a massive security violation.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that `FileSystemObject` like a hidden monster..

```
var fso, file, fileName = '/file.txt', fileContents = '';
if (fileName) {
    fso = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
    // don't worry about 'camelCase' typing, works both
    if (fso.fileExists(fileName)) {
        file = fso.openTextFile(fileName, 1);
        fileContents = file.readAll();
        // or loop over lines
        // while (!file.atEndOfStream) {
        //     fileContents += file.readLine();
        // }
        file.close();
    }
}
```

More info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/314cz14s(v=vs.85).aspx